# Is the character group of the character group of G isomorphic to G?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism

Let $S^1 = \{z \in C | |z| = 1\}$ be the unit circle in the complex field with well-known group structure. Let G be an abelian group and $\hat{G} = \{\chi \in Hom(G, S^1)\}$ be the character group. I know there is a homomorphism of groups

$$
\tau : G \longrightarrow \hat{\hat{G}}
$$
$$
g \mapsto \tau(g) : \chi \mapsto \chi(g)
$$
I know that $\tau$ is an isomorphism if G is finite. But what if G is an arbitrary abelian group?

Comment: Google for Pontriagin Duality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pontryagin duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_duality) is pretty restrictive ($G$ has a topology making it locally compact and $\widehat{G}$ is the group of continuous characters, with its own locally compact topology).

In general, with the axiom of choice and without restricting to continuous characters, it fails.

Try with $G=\bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty\Bbb{F}_p$ an infinite but countable $\Bbb{F}_p$ vector space.

$\widehat{G} \cong Hom(G,\Bbb{F}_p)\cong \prod_{n=1}^\infty\Bbb{F}_p$ is uncountable.

And $\widehat{\widehat{G}}$ is uncountable as well.

Without the axiom of choice we can't construct any character of $\Bbb{R/Q}$ nor prove that there are none and so we are stuck.